# mysqli_sql_exception: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, formularios

mysqli_sql_exception: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`users_web`.`users_login`, CONSTRAINT `users_login_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_user`) REFERENCES `users_data` (`id_user`))

Hola! he estado viendo post sobre el tema, y creo que el problema es que estoy insertando datos en 2 tablas distintas pero la 2º tiene un problema con la FK, creo que al intentar coger la referencia de la 1º tabla estuviera vacía y por eso salta el error. He intentado recuperar el id con una consulta, un select básico antes de insertar los datos en la 2º pero sigo con el error y estoy un poco atascado, a ver si me podéis ayudar.

El código:

```
            $nombre = $_POST["nombre"] ?? "";
            $apellidos = $_POST["apellidos"] ?? "";
            $email = $_POST["email"] ?? "";
            $tlf = $_POST["telefono"] ?? "";
            $fnacimiento = $_POST["fnacimiento"] ?? "";
            $direccion = $_POST["direccion"] ?? "";
            $sexo = $_POST["sexo"] ?? "";

            $usuario = $_POST["usuario"] ?? "";
            $password = $_POST["password"] ?? "";
            $password = hash('sha512', $password) ?? "";
            $rol = 'user' ?? "";

            # Introducimos datos en la tabla 1

            $datos_personales = "INSERT INTO users_data(nombre,apellidos,email,telefono,fecha_nacimiento,direccion,sexo) 
            VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

            $stmt = $conexion->prepare($datos_personales);
            $stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $nombre, $apellidos, $email, $tlf, $fnacimiento, $direccion,$sexo);
            $stmt->execute();
            # Ponemos en $outPut el total de filas insertadas
            $outPut['datos_personales'] = $stmt->affected_rows;

            # Recuperamos la PK (id_user) de la tabla 1 para introducirlo como FK en la tabla 2

            $id = "SELECT id_user FROM users_data" ?? "";

            # Introducimos datos en la tabla 2

            $datos_cuenta = "INSERT INTO users_login(id_user,usuario,contraseña,rol) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";

            $stmt = $conexion->prepare($datos_cuenta);
            $stmt->bind_param("ssss",$id,$usuario,$password,$rol);
            $stmt->execute();
            # Ponemos en $outPut el total de filas insertadas
            $outPut['datos_cuenta'] = $stmt->affected_rows;
```

Y el script de la BD:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users_data(
    id_user INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nombre VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
    apellidos VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR (45) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    telefono VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
    fecha_nacimiento DATE NOT NULL,
    direccion VARCHAR (30),
    sexo VARCHAR (15),
    PRIMARY KEY(id_user)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users_login(
    id_login INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_user INT NOT NULL,
    usuario VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    contraseña VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
    rol VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id_login),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_user) REFERENCES users_data (id_user)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS citas(
    id_cita INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_user INT NOT NULL,
    fecha_cita DATE NOT NULL,
    motivo_cita VARCHAR (50),
    PRIMARY KEY(id_cita),
    FOREIGN KEY(id_user) REFERENCES users_data(id_user)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS noticias(
    id_noticia INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_user INT NOT NULL ,
    titulo VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    imagen VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    texto VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
    fecha DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_noticia),
    FOREIGN KEY(id_user) REFERENCES users_data(id_user)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Es evidente que si tienes declaradas reglas de integridad referencial e intentas insertar valores vacíos o nulos en las columnas dependientes te dará el error que mencionas. Entonces, verifica por qué esos valores son nulos o vacíos. Por otra parte, puede que usar disparadores (triggers) sea una mejor opción, pero eso ya depende de la realidad de tus tablas.

Comment: @A.Cedano He hecho un var_dump de la variable $id y efectivamente salta null, pero no entiendo porque no funciona,  tampoco con _$id = $conexion -> insert_id_, como podría hacer para recuperar el id de tabla 1 o si que estoy haciendo mal para que no coja el valor?

Comment: Yo veo al menos dos cosas extrañas en tu contexto. ¿Esto qué significa exactamente **`$id = "SELECT id_user FROM users_data" ?? "";`** ? Y ¿qué hace el `UNIQUE` en esta parte del `CREATE TABLE`: **`id_user INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT`** si es `AUTO_INCREMENT` y además `PRIMARY KEY` el `UNIQUE` sobra. Y, si quieres el último id generado, puedes usar `insert_id`, ¿cuál es el problema con usarlo?

Comment: Vale ahora sí funciona todo bien! tienes razón quite el UNIQUE supongo que se me coló e intentaba recuperar el id con un select, he puesto la del insert id justo después del execute y todo se introduce bien, gracias!! tengo una última duda, al pinchar el submit y enviar los datos la página te redirige al archivo que esta en el action del form, mientras que sólo quiero que se refresque la página y listo, esto lo podría hacer con un añadiendo  en el js un addlistener al submit y que haga un location.reload?

Comment: Para que se quede en la misma página, puedes ponerlo así: `action="#"`, aunque lo mejor de lo mejor es usar Ajax o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript, así, puedes comunicar con el servidor para hacer las inserciones por ejemplo y recibir la respuesta del servidor y actualizar parte del contenido de la página sin recargar.

Comment: Perdón, se me olvidó responder, al final usé la función header de php muy sencilla y funciona perfecto. Gracias por vuestra ayuda, un saludo!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo al menos dos problemas en lo que estás implementando.

En primer lugar, esto no tiene ningún sentido:

```
$id = "SELECT id_user FROM users_data" ?? "";
```

Al hacer eso, lo que haces es declarar que el valor de `$id` es **la cadena** `SELECT id_user FROM users_data`. No entiendo qué pretendes con eso.

En segundo lugar, la extensión `mysqli` posee una propiedad para obtener el último `id` de una tabla, dicha propiedad es **[`insert_id`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.insert-id.php)** y se puede encontrar tanto en el objeto de conexión (`mysqli_connection`), como en el objeto de la consulta preparada (`mysqli_stmt`).

Pero, es importante tener en cuenta que `insert_id` sólo funciona **cuando la tabla tiene una columna declarada como `AUTO_INCREMENT`**.

Y esto podría estar dando problemas en tu contexto, porque esta declaración no tiene sentido:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users_data(
    id_user INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nombre VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
    apellidos VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR (45) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    telefono VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
    fecha_nacimiento DATE NOT NULL,
    direccion VARCHAR (30),
    sexo VARCHAR (15),
    PRIMARY KEY(id_user)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Llama la atención que declares la columna `id_user` así:

```
id_user INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,

...

PRIMARY KEY(id_user)
```

¿Qué sentido tiene ahí el `UNIQUE`? Si la columna es `AUTO_INCREMENT` y además es `PRIMARY KEY`, no tiene ningún sentido declararla como `UNIQUE`, porque ya lo es por el hecho de ser `PRIMARY KEY`. Por tanto, la declaración correcta de tu tabla debería ser:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users_data(
    id_user INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nombre VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
    apellidos VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR (45) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    telefono VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
    fecha_nacimiento DATE NOT NULL,
    direccion VARCHAR (30),
    sexo VARCHAR (15),
    PRIMARY KEY(id_user)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

En cuanto al código, podrías obtener el último ID con algo como esto:

```
        # Introducimos datos en la tabla 1

        $datos_personales = "INSERT INTO users_data(nombre,apellidos,email,telefono,fecha_nacimiento,direccion,sexo) 
        VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        $stmt = $conexion->prepare($datos_personales);
        $stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $nombre, $apellidos, $email, $tlf, $fnacimiento, $direccion,$sexo);
        $stmt->execute();

        /*
           $id será el último valor 
           de la columna id_user
        */
        $id=$conexion->insert_id;
```

#### Post-Data

Esto se podría resolver de una mejor manera programando un disparador (trigger) que se encargue de insertar en la tabla `users_login` los datos necesarios cuando ocurra una inserción en la tabla `users_data` o viceversa.

Para más detalles sobre los disparadores, puedes consultar [este artículo](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/).

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos partes en tu pregunta

la primera, como obtener el ultimo id, es bastante sencillo, usa la funcion de php
insert_id
https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.insert-id.php

La segunda parte es sobre las relaciones de tus tablas. Si insertando el ultimo id no te funciona, es posible que las relaciones están mal. Tendríamos que ver que ver las tablas y la relación

Comment: No conocía la función, pero sería lo mismo esto _$id = $conexion -> insert_id;_ que la línea que tengo puesta (_$id = "SELECT id_user FROM users_data" ?? "";_) no?  el script de la bd lo acabo de dejar arriba

Comment: No es lo mismo. Tu estas haciendo una nueva consulta, de la otra forma, en la misma consulta te esta devolviendo el id que acaba de añadir. (Digamos te ahorras una consulta y tienes la seguridad de tener el id añadido. Como dice @a-cedano en el comentario, tienes que usar el objeto de la consulta. Veo que has puesto la tablas,   y la relación parece que esta bien, así  que te deberia funcionar al obtener el id. Lo que no entiendo es la razón para separarlo en dos tablas y tener que hacer dos insert y dos consultas cuando necesites los datos